# $a(x) dx^{i_1} \wedge ... \wedge dx^{i_n}$ is not a tensor?

Tags: differential-geometry

I just would like to check something.

In the book *The Geometry of Physics* by Theodore Frankel, they talk about the quantity : $a(x) dx^{i_1} \wedge ... \wedge dx^{i_p}$ where $a$ is a function. They don't say explicitely it is a tensor in the sense it transforms well but I think they suggest it (I may be wrong but I want to check the following with you).

Here is the screenshoot :

[image]

$dx^I$ means $dx^{i_1} \wedge ... \wedge dx^{i_p}$

But for me as $a$ is a function, its expression will be the same in all coordinate systems. So we have an ill-defined quantity.

Indeed :

$$a(x) dx^{i_1} \wedge ... \wedge dx^{i_p} = a(x(y)) \frac{\partial x^{i_1}}{\partial y^{j_1}} \frac{\partial x^{i_p}}{\partial y^{j_p}}dy^{j_1} \wedge ... \wedge dy^{j_p}$$

And this quantity is not equal to :

$$a(x(y)) dy^{i_1} \wedge ... \wedge dy^{i_p}$$

Thus the expression is not the same in all coordinates system. Thus there is a problem.

A tensor would be $b_{i_1...i_p}(x) dx^{i_1} \wedge ... \wedge dx^{i_p}$

where $b$ would be the coefficient in $\{x\}$ of a p time contravariant tensor.

Am I right ? Is there a mistake in the book ? Or did I misunderstood something ?

Comment: It's a linear map on $n$ vectors, isn't it? So it's a tensor.

Comment: Yes but $\partial_i A_j dx^i dx^j$ is a linear map on 2 vectors but it is not a tensor as it doesn't respect the law of transformation for example. Isn't it the same kind of problem here ? (My question is probably very naive)

Comment: How do you define tensors?

Comment: @edm I define tensors as linear maps that eats k vectors and p covectors and returns a number, AND that has the same expression in all basis. $\partial_i A_j - \partial_j A_i  dx^i dx^j$ where $A$ is a vector is a tensor because if I express it in $\{x \}$ or $\{y\}$ basis it has the same expression. But $\partial_i A_j dx^i dx^j$ is not. Isn't that true ??

Comment: When it is something like $dx^1\wedge dx^2$, we usually call it a differential form rather than a tensor, which is a function that assigns to each point an alternating tensor.

Comment: @edm in fact I still have my problem, I edited my message to be more accurate

Comment: If you can, please state which book you are using.

Comment: @edm The geometry of physics from Theodore Frankel. Page 73 :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you may have misunderstood what your book.

I suppose that by $a(x)dx^I$ they want to denote the representation of a $p$-form in a given chart (i.e. with a fixed set of coordinates), otherwise it wouldn't make any sense to talk about the $dx_i$'s, which are the canonical differentials in *the chart choosen*.

So basically the expression gives the coordinates of a tensor field in a given chart (hence it is a tensor field in the given chart).

**Edit**: as a little addendum allow me to remind you that tensor field representations (in coordinates) are not supposed to remain unchanged under change of coordinates. In particular vector coordinates are supposed to change contravariantly while the covectors coordinates change covariantly.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Oh ok, so in fact the $a=a_I$ has the good law of transformation and there is not the problem I thought there were ?

Comment: @StarBucK I think so. In particular take a look to small edit I made.

Comment: Okay, thanks a lot

Answer (score 3):

Seems that you have found the solution yourself. But more precisely, you should really talk about the sum:
$$ \alpha = \sum_{i_1,...,i_p} a_{i_1,...,i_p}dx^{i_1} \wedge ... \wedge dx^{i_p}$$
Then the differential form $\alpha$ is independent of coordinates if under the coordinate transformation $x=x(y)$ you have:
$$ \alpha = \sum_{i_1,...,i_p} a_{i_1,...,i_p}dx^{i_1} \wedge ... \wedge dx^{i_p} =
 \sum_{j_1,...,j_p} \left(\sum_{i_1,...,i_p} a_{i_1,...,i_p}\frac{\partial x^{i_1}}{\partial y^{j_1}}\cdots \frac{\partial x^{i_p}}{\partial y^{j_p}} \right) dy^{j_1}\wedge ... \wedge dy^{j_p} 
$$
The parenthesis then 'defines' $\tilde{a}_{j_1,...,j_p}$ in the new coordinates and is said to transform as a $(0,p)$ tensor.

Comment: Well in fact I though I had but I did'nt. I insist on the fact that $a_{i}$ is not the component of a covariant vector but is a **function**. If I write $a_i(x) dx^i$, with $a_i$ a function this quantity is not a tensor as if I change of basis my linear form I will end up with : $a_i(x(y)) \frac{\partial x^i} {\partial y^j} dy^j$ which is not equal to $a_i(x(y)) dy^i$. Thus we don't have the same form in all coordinates system, thus even if it eats a vector to give a number it is not a tensor. Do you agree with me ? (that's a newbie question)

Comment: In fact it seems to be what you said so I guess there is a mistake in the book. I edit my message to put a screenshoot to be sure of it.

Comment: The screenshot is correct. It corresponds to having a diff form $\alpha=a_I dx^I$ where there is only one non-zero term in the $x$-coordinate system. Now, transforming to another system your will in general get a lot of non-zero terms and it will look like $\alpha = \sum_J \tilde{a}_J dy^J$. In the screen-shot example there is an implicit sum over $j$. In your previous comment, note that if $a_i$ didn't change then it would be a $(0,0)$ tensor (which it is not).

Comment: Ok, so in fact we have $a(x)$ that is indeed a p-times covariant component. And there is not this problem.